# Performance comparison between compare-and-swap and blocking algorithm

Tags: java, concurrency, blocking, lock-free

I have a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` that I use as the underlying datastructure. On every put call, I add a unique incremented value to the list. I have both the synchronized and compare-and-swap versions of this method. When I have few threads (e.g., 5) and doing 10 million puts in all, I see that synchronized version works much better. When I have many threads (e.g., 2000) and do the same number of puts in total, I see that CAS works much better. Why does CAS underperform in comparison to blocking algorithm with fewer threads?

```
// AtomicReference<Foo> latestValue that is initialized
    public void put(Double value) {
        Foo currentValue;
        while (true) {
            currentValue = latestValue.get();
            Foo newValue = new Foo(value);
            if (latestValue.compareAndSet(currentValue, newValue)) {
                historyList.add(newValue);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Statistics

```
NON-BLOCKING
Threads 2000
Puts per thread 10000
Put time average    208493309

BLOCKING
Threads 2000
Puts per thread 10000
Put time average    2370823534


NON-BLOCKING
Threads 2
Puts per thread 10000000
Put time average    13117487385

BLOCKING
Threads 2
Puts per thread 10000000
Put time average    4201127857
```

Comment: I'd say your observation **is** the catch.

Comment: @Fildor can you elaborate?

Comment: If you have more Threads involved it gets more important to work lock-free. Because the probability of collisions will be much higher. If you only have a few Threads then an implementation with less overhead might perform better even if it includes locking.

Comment: @Fildor Ok, that part I understand. What I do not understand is why is it that when there are fewer threads, CAS performs bad.

Comment: What is your definition of "bad"? And how did you implement CAS? Maybe there is some room for optimization?

Comment: My definition of bad is only relative. Rather worse is the word. CAS takes 3 times longer than blocking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR** because in uncontended case JVM will optimize `synchronized` and replace it with CAS lock.

In your CAS case you got overhead: you are trying to do some computation even if your CAS will fail. Of course it's nothing in comparison to real mutex acquiring, what usually happens when you are using `synchronized`.

But JVM isn't stupid and when it can see that lock you are currently acquiring is uncontented, it just replaces real mutex with CAS lock (or even with simple store in case of biased locking).
So for two threads in case of `synchronized` you are measuring just a CAS, but in case of your own CAS implementation you're also measuring time for allocating Foo instance, for compareAndSet and for get().

For 2000 threads JVM doesn't perform CAS-optimization, so your implementation outperforms mutex acquiring as expected.

Comment: I've edited my answer for your case to explain it better

Comment: Is there any source you can point to me about JVM CAS-optimization?

Comment: @user592748 of course. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/6-performance-137236.html#2.1.3 it's official paper, there you can find some comments from Brian Goetz http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp10185/index.html/ . If you are interesting in particular implementation you can find some info here: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/a5685a980b17/src/share/vm/oops/markOop.hpp and actual interpreting here: src/cpu/x86/vm/templateInterpreter or in hotspot/src/share/vm/interpreter/